# Git errors while pushing

Tags: git, github, command-line, atlassian-sourcetree

I input "git add -A" and it gives me an error:

> "fatal: Unknown index entry format 65540000".

I looked for every other sources and could not figure out what this really means.

Then, I tried pushing using sourcetree and got an error like below:
[image]

All I recently added are codes and few imagefiles. Not sure what is causing the problem. The last commit I did is a month ago, btw. This is my first commit after I upgraded my xcode to 7.0 version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my first commit after I upgraded my xcode to 7.0 version

Then try to clone again your repo with XCode7, and add your change in that new local repo.
It should work better in a clone entirely managed by the new XCode.

Comment: I will give a shot! Thank you